# Sending single characters to Telnet

Tags: printf, windows-ce, telnet

I have a single-threaded program that runs on a WEC2013 device. Since the device has no display I use a Telnet connection to the device.

I want to show some progress indication. For that purpose I added a `printf` statement:

```
void DoTimeConsumingCalculation()
{
   for (auto step = 0; step < 100; ++step)
   {
      // calculate, takes about 10 seconds
      CrunchNumbers();
      // keep the user happy
      printf(".");
   }
   printf("\n");
}
```

Instead of issuing dots during the calculation this results in a complete line that is sent to the client when the `\n` is sent.

I experiemented with `fflush(stdout);` and `setvbuf(0, _IONBF,0);` without any effect. Even `fprintf(stderr, '.');` gives the same result.

But when I use `printf("..");` I get two dots immediately. But this is not the output I need.

How can I convince the C-runtime library to send each single character?